# How to do operators in multiple select statements? MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, operators, mysql-workbench, operator-precedence

The goal is Forested land **/** (forested **+** non-forested land area)

here is what I have tried, but shows errors such as

> operand should contain 1 column(s)

below I just  tried to add up first. Need your help

```
SELECT DISTINCT Year, State, Total_Forested

(SELECT Distinct Year, State, Hectares AS Total_Forested  FROM forest_greenproject.`forested and non-forested areas, malaysia, 2000 - 2017`  WHERE Category = 'Non-Forested')
+
(SELECT Distinct Year, State, Hectares AS Total_Forested   FROM forest_greenproject.`forested and non-forested areas, malaysia, 2000 - 2017`   WHERE Category = 'Forested') 

FROM forest_greenproject.`forested and non-forested areas, malaysia, 2000 - 2017`
```

Comment: Use conditional aggregation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply conditional aggregation, as @Akina already pointed out in the comments section.

That is, you're using an aggregation (the `SUM` aggregation function) but only on those values which satisfy a condition, in this case `Category = 'Forested'`. Then you can divide this value by the sum of all "*hectares*" values (assuming that you can have only two choices in the "*Category*" field - either forested or not).

When you apply an aggregation (like the `SUM`), don't forget to add a `GROUP BY` clause that should contain every non-aggregated field in the `SELECT` clause, namely "*Year*" and "*State*".

```
SELECT Year, 
       State, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Category = 'Forested' THEN Hectares END) / SUM(Hectares) 
FROM forest_greenproject.`forested and non-forested areas, malaysia, 2000 - 2017`
GROUP BY Year,
         State
```